Focus DataGridView control on a specific cell
I know there are multiple posts on this but their solution do not work for me.
In a WinForms application in .Net 8.0, I have added a DataGridView control.
Trying to set the focus to a specific cell does not work.
The focus moves to the correct row but always stays in column 0.
I define a DataTable dt:
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Variable", typeof(System.String));
        dt.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(System.String));

populate it with soem data and set it to the DataSource of the DataGridView.
No event handlers are added to the DataGridView. No properties set, only
what is shown here.
There are a million hits on Google on how to set the focus on a specific cell
and they are mostly saying the same thing - but it does not work.
In the below code:
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0];
        Logger.Write(LogLevel.Debug, $"Current Cell: Row {dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex}, Column {dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex}");

        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[1];
        dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[1].Selected = true;
        dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);
        dataGridView1.Focus();

        Logger.Write(LogLevel.Debug, $"Current Cell: Row {dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex}, Column {dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex}");

The cell is being correctly set to 0,0 on the first command at the top, but the 2nd
line below trying to set it to row 1 and column 1 only moves it to row 1 and it stays
at column 0.
Yet the log file shows that the DataGridView "thinks" it has been executed:
   28-Nov-2024 17.07.33 Debug: Current Cell: Row 0, Column 0
   28-Nov-2024 17.07.33 Debug: Current Cell: Row 1, Column 1

So what is the solution to handle that ...?

dataGridView1.Focus(); moves the focus to the Control itself. Where does it land, depends on the SelectionMode. Remove it. It also doesn't make any sense, given that you have dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true); before that

Not working without the Focus method either, I added both BeginEdit and Focus later to try to handle

To select a Cell, you just need something like dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[1, 1]; (Column 1, Row 1), nothing else. Provided that SelectionMode is not set to FullRowSelect, of course

I solved it.
The solution was simple and related to something I did not realize impacts this issue:
When issuing the commands
     dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[1];

the dataGridView1 control must be on the CURRENTLY ACTIVE PART OF THE FORM.
My control was on a 2nd page of a TabPage control but the form opens on a different page and the above code was in the initialization code (not even in the Form initialization, but in a method deferred by a timer, so I had already tried with Invoke which didn't work either).
I forced the form to open on the TabPage which contains the DataGridView, and it worked fine.
In hindsight it sounds almost silly.
